# $A \lor I = A \equiv A \land I = I$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

Is the following statement a tautology?
$$A \lor I = A\Leftrightarrow A \land I = I$$

where $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ logical matrix and $I$ is the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix.

Comment: What do you think? Why do you think it?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think that it is (a tautology) because I can't find a counter example. We used $A \lor I = A$ in class to determine whether a relation matrix is reflexive. I asked my teacher whether $A \land I = I$ works as well and he said no, but I found his reasoning insufficient. If the main diagonal of a relation matrix is reflexive, $A \land I$ should equal $I$ and vice versa.

Comment: Define those two matrix operators.